# BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

The API works fine when I am running it from Intellij IDE using the same Tomcat 8.5 files. However when I deploy the war to the server I get the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/C:/Users/Bob/Documents/Tomcat%208.5/webapps/database_war%20exploded/WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.divcon.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>database-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Divcon Database API</name>
    <description>Diversified Control API</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>api</finalName>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1207</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

cxf-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
                            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <jaxrs:server id="DatabaseLoginService" address="/authenticationservice">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="dbLoginBean" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <jaxrs:server id="DatabasePermissionService" address="/authorizationservice">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="dbPermissionBean" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="dbLoginBean" class="net.divcon.database.authentication.AuthenticationServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="dbPermissionBean" class="net.divcon.database.authorization.AuthorizationServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider"/>

</beans>
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have spent days googling the error in various ways however I have not had any luck resolving it.

Comment: What is your jdk version?

Comment: @Spara "Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Comment: @Spara I changed it to use: jdk1.8.0_201. This solved my issue. Throw that into an answer and I will mark it correct for pointing me in the right direction. Bonus points for telling me why it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java 11 JAXB APIs are completely removed from the JDK. So backing to JDK 8 will solve your issue.
There is a clean solution for JDKs >= 9 which suggested here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52872160/4431053

Comment: Solved my issue and provided an explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```